# method that takes parameter of multiple type and decide the behavior at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a method like this

```
square(num: number | string): number {
 // 
}
```

In this method I want to check the parameter's data type and invoke the logic accordingly. How do to that in TS?

Edit:

Specific types in question

```
export type KV<T extends string | number> = {
    key: string;
    val: T;
}
```

```
export type LogicalKV<T extends string | number> = {
    logicalOperator: LogicalOperator
    filters?: Filter<T>[];
    logicalFilters?: LogicalFilter<T>[];
}
```

Function

```
class Foo {

    read(filter: KV<string | number> | LogicalKV <string | number>):  Promise<void> {
    // if filter is of KV do this, else do that
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types are stripped at runtime unfortunately. But you could go the good old way of `typeof`

```
if (typeof num === "string") {/*it's string here*/} else {/*it's number here*/}
```

Typescript will also understand that and coerce to an appropriate type in each branch.

In case of custom types, like yours, it's going to be a bit different. [Algebraic data types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) are involved. It's also not too pretty when you instantiate it, but you have to deal with passing runtime string "kinds" one way or another.

```js
export type KV = {
  kvField: string;
  kind: "kv";
};
export type LogicalKV = {
  logicalKvField: number;
  kind: "logicalKv";
};

const KVInstance: KV = {
  kind: "kv",
  kvField: "foo"
};

const LogicalKVInstance: LogicalKV = {
  kind: "logicalKv",
  logicalKvField: 1
};

type FilterArg = KV | LogicalKV;

const fn = (f: FilterArg) => {
  switch (f.kind) {
    case "kv":
      // ts knows it's KV
      f.kvField;
      return;
    case "logicalKv":
      // ts knows it's LogicalKV
      f.logicalKvField;
      return;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have my own types (string and number are just for illustration) - I get type of num as `undefined` at runtime. Is there a way to associate polymorphic method with type?

Comment: For your own types, [algebraic data types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) is an option. Could you please add your types into the question? The solution depends on specific types. If you get `typeof === "undefined"`, something's off with typing as well it seems.

Comment: Thanks @Igor, I updated question with specific types in question

Comment: There you are (see the edit). WIth custom types, it's pretty much different. @user3833308

Comment: I ended up fixing it with `filter.hasOwnProperty('logicalOperator')? do this : do that` - is this acceptable form?

Comment: Quite. It gives you fewer compile time guarantees but as long as you watch its correctness it's all good.